# Hover animation in navigation being blocked if it touches the mouse

Tags: jquery, dom, animation

Firstly apologies for the terrible title. Couldn't think of a better way to word it.

Secondly this bug does not seem to be happening for me in Chrome, but it is in Firefox and I have not tested any other browsers.

What I am trying to achieve is an on hover animation for my menu items, where brackets envelop the menu item as you hover over them, however my mouse appears to be blocking the animation.

I understand why - it is because as soon as my mouse touches the bracket, it is no longer hovering the nav item, so it is triggering the mouseleave function. Problem is I have absolutely no idea how to prevent this.

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="navHoverLeft">[</div>
<div id="navHoverRight">]<div>
```

CSS

```
nav{ 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

nav ul{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
}

nav li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    right: 50%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 15px 25px 0 15px;
}

nav a{
    color: #fff;
}

nav a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

#navHoverLeft, #navHoverRight{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 500;
    color: #f33;
    float: left;
}
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#navHoverLeft').css('top', $('nav ul li.active').offset().top - 1);
      $('#navHoverLeft').css('left', $('nav ul li.active').offset().left - 13);
      $('#navHoverRight').css('top', $('nav ul li.active').offset().top - 1);
      $('#navHoverRight').css('left', $('nav ul li.active').offset().left + $('.active').width() + 3);

      $('nav ul li a').on('mouseenter', function(){
        $('#navHoverLeft').animate({
          "left" : $(this).parent().offset().left - 13
        }, 500).clearQueue();

        $('#navHoverRight').animate({
          "left" : $(this).parent().offset().left + $(this).parent().width() + 3
        }, 500).clearQueue();
      });

      $('nav ul li a').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $('#navHoverLeft').animate({
          "left" : $('.active').offset().left - 13
        }, 500).clearQueue();

        $('#navHoverRight').animate({
          "left" : $('.active').offset().left + $('.active').width() + 3
        }, 500).clearQueue();
      });
    });
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RCG8q/) of it all together.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation isn't "blocked", it's just that mouseleave is triggered as soon as e.g. `#havhoverright` is below the mouse. To fix this, you'll need to take your hover elements into account while animating and simply ignore any mouseleave/mouseenter events on those.

You'll need to refactor quite a little bit, I suggest you start by delegating the events to a common parent (that you'll have to introduce).

[edit]
Forget what I wrote, your problem is easily solved with CSS (at least in Firefox):

```
nav li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    right: 50%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 15px 25px 0 15px;
    /* >>>> */ z-index: 600; /* <<<< */
}
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but surely my event listener for mouseleave always needs to be on the `<li>` or the `<a>` in order or me to get the desired effect where the brackets return to the active page on mouseleave and the bracket touching the mouse will always cause this problem?

I mean, I have zero listeners on the bracket divs at the moment.

Comment: This does make the animation go behind the text, and although it is slightly more noticeable in my actual development code as the text is a lot bigger than it is in he fiddle, it is still barely noticeable at all. So I'm gonna take it, thank you.